# $.cycle and dynamic content after a click event

Tags: asp.net, jquery-cycle

I  want to apply cycle to the div block with dynamic content. This content will be generated after a click event. Once i click the image it is working after that it is not working.

Code:

```
$("div.cls img").click(function() {

  ....  Adding the content


 $('#myDiv').cycle({
            fx: 'scrollHorz',
            speed: 3500,
            timeout: 0, continuous: true,
            pause: 1, sync: 1
        }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">
 <div>
 <a id="i1"> abc</a>
 <a id="i2"> abcd</a>
 <a id="i3"> abce</a>
   <a id="i4"> abcf</a>
 <a id="i5"> abcg</a>
 <a id="i6"> abch</a>
</div>
 <div>
 <a id="i11"> abc1</a>
 <a id="i21"> abcd1</a>
 <a id="i31"> abce1</a>
   <a id="i41"> abc1f</a>
 <a id="i51"> abcg1</a>
 <a id="i61"> abch1</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question with more details, and specify that your problem lies with using $.cycle and *dynamic content*.  For example, when I answered, I had *no idea* that you are actually trying to load the "slides" dynamically.

It is still not clear that your example works fine, *until you start trying to load content dynamically*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Try calling `$.cycle()` again after adding your dynamic content.  Also, use Firebug to ensure that your content is being generated correctly.

If that doesn't work, then it looks like you will have to modify the cycle plugin to support dynamically adding "slides", or write your own solution.

---

From http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/:

> How it Works
>
> The plugin provides a method called
>   cycle which is invoked on a container
>   element. Each child element of the
>   container becomes a "slide". Options
>   control how and when the slides are
>   transitioned.

So, you can leave your Javascript alone, but the HTML should look like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <div>
    <a id="i1"> abc</a>
    <a id="i2"> abcd</a>
    <a id="i3"> abce</a>
    <a id="i4"> abcf</a>
    <a id="i5"> abcg</a>
    <a id="i6"> abch</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a id="i11"> abc1</a>
    <a id="i21"> abcd1</a>
    <a id="i31"> abce1</a>
    <a id="i41"> abc1f</a>
    <a id="i51"> abcg1</a>
    <a id="i61"> abch1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, you should never have more than one element on a page with the same ID.

Comment: Hi i have tried this option too. if i hard coded the same html it is working. If i added the code dynamically it is not working.

Comment: Then there are two possibilities:  1) You are dynamically generating the HTML incorrectly.  Use Firebug to find out.  2) You are calling `$.cycle()` BEFORE generating the HTML - it has to be called AFTER.